# Binding to properties defined in the base classes in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, inheritance, mvvm

Let's say I have three classes:
BaseClassA,BaseClassB,ClassC.
The flow is the following:
ClassC : BaseClassB: BaseClassA.
ClassC is a ViewModel and I bind some Property (let's name it SomeProperty) which is defined in the BaseClassA level.
When I write in the view `ItemsSource = {Binding SomeProperty}` the binding fails.
The binding works perfectly when SomeProperty is defined at the BaseClassB level or if I define it at the ClassC level e.g. SomeProperty `{get {return base.SomeProperty}}`
Is such a behaviour by design or am I missing something?

[upd]
The property is of DomainCollectionView type.
I update the property in the OnLoadEntitiesCompleted method of the BaseClassA instance.

Previously I had only ClassC and BaseClassA objects and everything worked perfectly indeed.
After introducing the mid-tier BaseClassB object the binding stopped to work.
Is it something specific to DomainCollectionView

I can't share the code so I'll post the meaningful parts. If it's not enough I'm willing to share more:

```
public abstract BaseClassA
{
protected DomainCollectionView CollectionView {get;}
}

public abstract BaseClassB : BaseClassA

public ClassC : BaseClassB
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Assuming your example is accurate:* Your property is not **public** so binding fails.

Nothing at all to do with your inheritance.

Change it to:

```
public DomainCollectionView CollectionView {get;}
```

and try again.

Comment: Yep, that's the issue. It was public before though, Reminds me again to make one change at a time

Answer (score 0):

You are missing something. Binding to properties in base classes works fine in SL. Property `IsEnabled`, for instance, is defined in `UIElement`, which is a 5th level ancestor of `Button`.

Comment: As HiTech stated, your property is protected, so assuming your view does not belong to this inheritance hierarchy, it can't access it. Change it to public.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you implement ClassC:SomeProperty that does nothing but delegating to an equally named property in a base class? The only way the break databinding to properties defined in base classes is to make them private or protected.